# Vba 'on error' handler does not appear to work

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, onerror

I am having difficulties trying to understand how basic ON ERROR  handler works in VBA's excel (if at all).  In the example below, I am dividing 6/0  expecting ON ERROR kick in, ie ignore the error-triggering line (y=6/0).

```
Sub UsingResumeNext()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    x = 6
    y = 6 / 0
    x = 7
End Sub
```

However when I run the code an pop up alert window comes up saying 'Runtime error 11, Division by zero',see attachment ( [image: screenshot of an error] ).

I am confused.. Should't the on error effectively 'silence' alert window from showing up?  It looks like the on error handler does not work.  Anyone has suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get that. try putting the code in a new workbook and run it.

Comment: @ScottCraner, apologies but you do not get what:  the question or the behavior of the on error handler?

Comment: I get no error when I run it.

Comment: @ScottCraner, really???  that's very interesting... Could it be the Excel's options then?  I closed everything, opened a new workbook, re-ran it, still the same alert window pops up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your VBE options, make sure you're not *breaking on all errors*:

[image: VBE Options / General tab]

Comment: I knew there was some sort of setting, just not where.  Now that I see this I remember.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mat's Mug!!  This solved the problem!  I was actually going crazy over it, pondering what's going on...